# What limits data rate through a medium keep on increasing?

Tags: communication

We know data rate is bits per second. It can be also considered as baud rate(symbols per second) times the number of bits in symbol. So, if to increase data rate, we can increase baud rate or we can increase number of bits in a symbol. Why can't we keep on increasing these two? Can someone explain what happens with these 2 occasions separately?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is essentially a physics question.  We can play all sorts of games with how to physically represent a signal (hence, getting more bits per baud), but at the end of the day you can only physically convey so much information for any given rate of change of a signal.  If you want to communicate faster, you have to up the frequency, which means having signals that change faster in time -- and nature ultimately limits how fast you can change the signal.

See:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Nyquist_rate

This gets even worse when you add noise:
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shannon%E2%80%93Hartley_theorem